# std::chrono create constant time laps

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

how can I compare if the difference between 2 timpoints is greated than a certain fix time? I can mesure time but I do not manage to create a constant with the time I want.

So far I have the following code:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
...
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2- t1);
```

i thought to create a constant and compare as follow:

```
std::chrono::milliseconds maxTime;
maxTime = 5000;
if(elapsedTime > maxTime){
    //....
}
```

The assignment of maxTime does not work.
Any idea how to do so without passing the integer via the constructor)?

Comment: can you post whole code and compilation error? Posted fragments compile on Coding Grounds (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php). Have you included `<chrono>` and proper compiler switches (`-std=c++11` in GCC)?

Comment: ah shit... i modified to make the answer and this works...
the problem is that I did not use the constructor but i tried to initialize with =.
do you know how to do so? i modify the question

Comment: uhm, `maxTime` is not an `int`, so you cannot assign a number to it. try: `maxTime = std::chrono::milliseconds(5000);`

Comment: You don't have to convert everything to the same units (milliseconds in your example) to compare.  And in C++14 you can use chrono literals.  You could say something as simple as `if (t2 - t1 > 5s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `maxTime` as `std::chrono::milliseconds` - that's why you cannot assign an `int` to it. If you have the amount of milliseconds that you want to assign to `maxTime` - let's call it `int myAmount` - use `maxTime = std::chrono::milliseconds(myAmount);` Of course, `maxTime` cannot be declared `const` then.

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your code like:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// ...
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2= std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto elapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1);
constexpr const std::chrono::milliseconds maxTime(5000); // <- this is the important change!
if(elapsedTime > maxTime){
    //...
}
```